# file_exists() returns false for remote URL

Tags: php

My `file_exists()` returns false even if provided image to check `https://www.google.pl/logos/2012/haring-12-hp.png` exist. Why?

Below I am presenting full failing PHP code ready to fire on localhost:

```
$filename = 'https://www.google.pl/logos/2012/haring-12-hp.png';
echo "<img src=" . $filename . " />";
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "The file $filename exists";
} else {
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}
```

Comment: So, you own google, eh? `Checks whether a file or directory exists.` Local only.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
$filename= 'https://www.google.pl/logos/2012/haring-12-hp.png';
$file_headers = @get_headers($filename);

if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found'){
      echo "The file $filename does not exist";
} else if ($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.0 302 Found' && $file_headers[7] == 'HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found'){
    echo "The file $filename does not exist, and I got redirected to a custom 404 page..";
} else {
    echo "The file $filename exists";
}
```

Comment: What If link instead of image (which dont exist) goes to 404 custom error page?

Comment: Hey, please look at the new changes to the code. Now checks if it landed on a custom 404 page.

Comment: Hmm well linking it to 404 page `http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/3716_obj_sprite.gif?id=1` fails.

Comment: k I had to change header from `if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found'){` to `if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found'){` Thanks, you've really helped me.

Comment: I dont think this is a good solution, because the error message can change any time from HTTP/1.0 to HTTP/1.X ..

Comment: Well... I'v tweaked a little the if condition....

if(strpos($file_headers[0], '200')>1 or strpos($file_headers[0], '304')>1)
 {
    echo "The file $filename exists";
}

might not be the perfect solution but... :))

Comment: I just tried this and it didn't work. It was saying a file was found when it doesn't exist.

Comment: i had to change your if statement to `if(strpos($file_headers[0], '404')){
//not exists 
}else{
//exist} 
`code`because of the same point Szymon Toda mentioned.

Answer (score 8):

A better if statement that not looks at http version

```
$file_headers = @get_headers($remote_filename);    
if (stripos($file_headers[0],"404 Not Found") >0  || (stripos($file_headers[0], "302 Found") > 0 && stripos($file_headers[7],"404 Not Found") > 0)) {
//throw my exception or do something
}
```

Answer (score 7):

> As of PHP 5.0.0, this function can also be used with some URL wrappers. Refer to Supported Protocols and Wrappers to determine which wrappers support stat() family of functionality.

From the [http(s) page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php) on [Supported Protocols and Wrappers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php):

> ```
> Supports stat()   No
> ```

Comment: What about URL: `http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/3716_obj_sprite.gif?id=2`?

Comment: It doesn't matter what the URL is; `http` and `https` don't support `stat()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $filename = "http://im.rediff.com/money/2011/jan/19sld3.jpg";

    $file_headers = @get_headers($filename);

    if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
    //return false; 
    echo "file not found";
    }else {
    //return true;  
    echo "file found";

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function check_file ($file){

    if ( !preg_match('/\/\//', $file) ) {
        if ( file_exists($file) ){
            return true;
        }
    }

    else {

        $ch = curl_init($file);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
        curl_exec($ch);
        $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        if($code == 200){
            $status = true;
        }else{
            $status = false;
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        return $status;

    }

    return false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can easely write simple url_exists function (if you use php framework like laravel. you can place this function in your model).

```
function URL_exists(string $url): bool
{
    return str_contains(get_headers($url)[0], "200 OK");
}
```

and can make call like $yourModelObject->URL_exists('full url string here');

Comment: What does this answer add in context of the existing ones, including those, that show the usage of `get_headers()` already? If you think there is something to correct or to extend on an existing answer, please leave a comment (requires some reputation) preferable over adding another answer.

Answer (score -1):

What you need is something like `url_exists`. Refer to the comments in the `file_exists` docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Here's one of the examples posted:

```
<?php
    function url_exists($url){
        $url = str_replace("http://", "", $url);
        if (strstr($url, "/")) {
            $url = explode("/", $url, 2);
            $url[1] = "/".$url[1];
        } else {
            $url = array($url, "/");
        }

        $fh = fsockopen($url[0], 80);
        if ($fh) {
            fputs($fh,"GET ".$url[1]." HTTP/1.1\nHost:".$url[0]."\n\n");
            if (fread($fh, 22) == "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found") { return FALSE; }
            else { return TRUE;    }

        } else { return FALSE;}
    }
?>
```

Comment: That example is pretty bad. It'd be better to just use cURL to make a `HEAD` request.