# Default image using php, can't tell if its catching id

Tags: php, image, if-statement

i'm trying to relay the id through this if statement to see if the file exits. If it does I want to use the id to grab that image from the corporation-logos/ folder. If not i'd like to simply show a default image. I can't tell if its catching the id or not as it keeps spitting out the default.

```
   if ($productCount > 0) {
        // get all the product details
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
        $id = $row["id"];
    $imgStock="http://www.stocksandstocks.com/corporation-logos/$id.jpg";
    $http_image="http://www.stocksandstocks.com/images/no-logo-default.png";

if(file_exists($imgStock))
{
  $imgPick = "$imgStock";
}
else
{
  $imgPick = "$http_image";
} 
echo "
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                               <div class='wrapPicks'>
                                  <div class='symbolPicks'>
                                      <div class='quoteTitle'>$quoteTitle</div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class='bgPicks'>
                                      <img src='$imgPick' height='50px' widht='80px' alt='stock symbol $quoteTitle logo' />
                                                <div class='separateWrap'>
                                                      <div class='quote'>
                                                          <b>Entry Price:</b> $$entry
                                                      </div>
                                                      <div class='quote'>
                                                          <b>Last trade:</b> $$lastPrice
                                                      </div>
                                                </div>    
                                                      <div class='quoteReturn'>
                                                              <b>Open P/L:</b> 
                                                              <div class='bigGreen'>
                                                              <span style=\"color: $color\">$positive $$profit </span>
                                                              </div>
                                                      </div>
                                 </div>
                            </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>";
```

Comment: Don't echo so much html... just do ?> your html here  <?php

Comment: I don't know that you can use `http://.....` when doing a `file_exists` check. Why don't use use a different variable withe the absolute path instead?

Comment: Regarding use of `file_exists` with `http://`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444059/file-exists-returns-false-even-if-file-exist-remote-url

Comment: instead of this "http://www.stocksandstocks.com/corporation-logos/$id.jpg" , try with local path from the script.

Comment: Thanks @MuhammedHedayet it was in fact the path issue. I changed it to corporation-logos/$id.jpg and it worked just fine

Comment: Thanks @showdev too for his useful link :)