# file_exists returns wrong value

Tags: php, http

I have the below code but it is returning wrong vlaue

```
if(file_exists("https://strutmymutt.com/file/pic/pages/13822542191645543571_400.jpg"))
    {
        echo "yes";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "no";
    }
```

any help on this?

even image exists on server, still it is returning "no"

Comment: `file_exists` is designed only for local files.

Comment: so how I can check this condition for the image

Comment: As of PHP 5.0.0, this function can also be used with some URL wrappers. Refer to Supported Protocols and Wrappers to determine which wrappers support stat() family of functionality.

Comment: See here for more information : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444059/file-exists-returns-false-even-if-file-exist-remote-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the PHP manual, [`file_exists`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) checks whether a file exists given a path to a file or directory.

This means that you cannot provide a URL to check, but rather an absolute or relative file path on the local filesystem. If you wish to check the file at a given URL, there is something in the comments of that page. Here is the relevant code:

```
$file = 'https://strutmymutt.com/file/pic/pages/13822542191645543571_400.jpg';
$file_headers = @get_headers($file);
if($file_headers[0] === 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
    echo 'no';
} else {
    echo 'yes';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the File Path to check if the file exists. Not the URL. Have a look here: http://php.net/file_exists

```
i.e.: file_exists('/Users/test/Desktop/1.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

file_exists is used for local file and not a url.

Answer (score 0):

`file_exists` only checks if a file exists **locally**.

You need to use a function to check the response from the server to check if that image exists:

[Check this answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444059/file-exists-returns-false-even-if-file-exist-remote-url)

Answer (score 0):

file_exists is working only on accessing local files..Do it this way instead...

```
$file = "file/pic/pages/13822542191645543571_400.jpg"; 
if(file_exists($file)) {
        echo "yes";
    }
    else {
        echo "no";
    }
```