# Laravel 5 File::exists not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a function to determine whether a user has an avatar or not based on the existence of a file named with his ID.jpg .

```
    public function hasAvatar()
    {
        if (File::exists(url('/media/avatars/' . $this->id . '.jpg')))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

for some reason, even though the file exists, the function always returns false.

Of course I got this at the head of the file:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
```

Comment: Is the media folder really in the filesystem root? Try removing the first `/`

Comment: the url facade automatically points to the public directory

Comment: What is the result of the `url()` call? `File::exists()` won't work with URLs.

Comment: Thank's. Please post this as an answer so I can make it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the result of `url()` to `File::exists()`, but that method does not work with URLs. That's why you are always getting `false`.

See [file_exists() returns false even if file exist (remote URL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444059/file-exists-returns-false-even-if-file-exist-remote-url)