# PHP and Apache file_exists not working from URL

Tags: php, apache, file-exists

The below code works (print "file found" ) find if I run it from command line

*php a.php*

But if I try to access it from browser http://localhost/a.php It prints "file not found".

Its really weird the same URL works fine on the different machine. I am clueless why it is not working.

I have already checked open_basedir it is already disabled and there is no entry in the httpd.conf

> ```
>  if(file_exists("/mnt/disk1/a.jpg"))
> { 
>   echo "file found";
> }     else
> { 
>   echo "file not found";    }   ?>
> ```

Comment: Have you checked the file permissions ? And does web have enough read access?

Comment: yes I have given 777 permission to the file

Comment: Are you try clearstatcache() ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [file\_exists() returns false even if file exist (remote URL)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444059/file-exists-returns-false-even-if-file-exist-remote-url)

Comment: You need to work with headers if you want to check for a file existence. In general the function works only with local files.

Comment: mitkosoft both are different . In that there are passing the URL here I am having complete path (I am checking local path only).

Comment: The web server account `www` will not be allowed to look at that file/folder

Comment: When running from command line your script is running with provelages of your user account. Apache is running as `www-data` (most commonly) and may not have access to this location.

Comment: Could it be that the web server is running in an isolated sandbox environment from which `/mnt/` is not accessible? Depending on the environment, you may get 'file not found' for anything outside of the local apache web root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The web server user account must have permission to read the file - this is a different user account than the one you use on console.

```
sudo chmod +rx /mnt/disk1/a.jpg
```

Apache also needs execute access on all folders to root.

```
sudo chmod +x /mnt/disk1
sudo chmod +x /mnt
```

Comment: thanks jeff somehow the same user create folder wittout executable permission